# processing kinect depth frame is very slow

Tags: ros, python, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am processing depth frame from Kinect try to find the ground floor, I am using simple method of computing for each pixel whether they belong to the equation of ground surface or not, I already computed `a,b,c,d` parameters of the equation of the ground, and I would like to process each pixel to be able to accept it as a ground pixel or now. Here is a snippet of my code for processing each frame:

```
for i in xrange(rows):
      for j in xrange(cols):
          x0 = frame[i, j]*math.cos((j-midx)*ax)*math.sin((i-midy)*ay)
          y0 = frame[i, j]*math.sin((j-midx)*ax)*math.sin((i-midy)*ay)
          z0 = frame[i, j]*math.cos((i-midy)*ay)    
          if abs(self.a*x0+self.b*y0+self.c*z0-self.d) < 0.0002:
              frame[i,j] = 10
```

for some reason each frame take more than 10 seconds to finish. This seems extremely slow. I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciate it.
EDIT:
Here are my computer info:

Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6400 @ 2.00GHz × 2

Ram: 3GB

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214660/processing-kinect-depth-frame-is-very-slow/) by [Samer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23151/samer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few comments:

- If you want speed, especially when processing point clouds, you'll have a better time with C++
- That hardware is pretty old
- There are a bunch of computations that you do multiple times per iteration in the inner loop. I'm not sure exactly what optimizations the python interpreter will do, but here are things that might help:
- Don't do multiple lookups of `frame[i, j]`. Assign it to a variable and then use that variable
- Only compute `(j-midx)*ax`, `(i-midy)*ay`, `math.sin((i-midy)*ay)`, etc. once
- Rather than looping, try to use numpy's array operations. They'll be much faster. [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) will probably be very useful here.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1